# Overlapping Identifiers

Tags: c++

I am writing the following classes in C++.

```
class SImage {
    ...
    public:
        SImage(char*);
}

class SImageProc {
    SImage S;
    ...
    public:
        SImageProc(SImage Im) { S = Im; };
}
```

When compiling I receive this referencing the line where I implement my constructor:

```
SImageProc.cpp:5:33: error: no matching function for call to 'SImage::SImage()'
```

I cannot figure out why it is interpreting my parameters as instantions of a class when implementing the SImageProc class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SImage` does not have a default constructor, because you have provided constructor `SImage(char*)`. This means the compiler no longer provides a default one. Something **elsewhere** in your code requires `SImage`, causing the error.

You need to provide a default constructor for `SImage`, or remove the code that requires it. It is not possible to say which one of the solutions is suitable without more details.

My wild guess would be that `SImageProc` has an `SImage` data member, and you are not initializing it in the constructor initialization list. This is how you would fix that problem:

```
SImageProc(SImage Im) : S(Im) {};
```

The explanation for that is that, by the time you reach a constructor's body, all data members and bases have been *initialized*. After initialization you can only modify them (in your example, you were *assigning* to `S`.) If you do not explicitly initialize data members and bases in the constructor initialization list, they (usually) get *default initialized*, which in the case of a user defined type means the default constructor is called. This is the source of the error.

Comment: This is counter intuitive. I don't understand why a parameter would require a default constructor. I wanted to pass an existing SImage object by value to the SImageProc class.

Comment: @Benji The logic is that if you have a special user-defined constructor, then it is likely that you either want to do something special in the default constructor, or you don't want one at all. But this doesn't stop you from passing something by value. That is an entirely unrelated issue.

Comment: I've updated my code to illustrate that my SImageProc class has an SImage field that I would like to define with the default constructor. Ideally, when the SImageProc class in initialized a SImage class is passed by value to set this field. This is where my confusion is, I don't know why this depends on the constructor of the parameter.

Comment: @Benji My wild guess was right :-) I added the fix you need. Will add a short explanation in a moment.